# Asynchronous message processing with Camel

Tags: java, design-patterns, apache-camel, esb, mq

I need help in finding out the best solution for following design problem.

I have a single front-end server which is used by our users. They submit  tasks which are supposed to run asynchronously and send an email when it gets completed. The task does the of  calling external API and update something there. There are accounts (not to be confused by user account) associated with an API. User will run a task for a particular account and once that account is engaged while doing api update, other tasks which want to update the API with same account has to wait. Please note that, uses doesn't have to wait, they might submit many tasks for the same (api) account. It is the system which will take care of putting tasks in Queue.
Queue will be listened by bunch of servers and as soon as account is freed up , next task will take will be picked up by some other server. Thus, we have multiple tasks submitted, updating api for multiple accounts.
I am looking at the Apache Camel as my solution to this, where front-end will submit the task on the bus and one of the servers will pick it up . However, If more than one tasks come for same account, only one can be executed as explained above, I want to keep the other task(s) for same account somewhere in the queue  (I am not sure how should I do that ) and as soon the account  is freed up the next message should be picked by one of the server in the cluster.
Any suggestion on better solution, not even sure if Camel is best one for this kind of problem. I am new to this kind of asynchronous design problem.

Answer (score 0):

Camel is perfect for such design. We used it in very similar scenarios and it offers out-of-the-box everything you need (transformations, async calls, etc).

My suggestion:

1. Use JMS server with 1 queue per API account
2. Create front service to get user calls (e.g. SOAP/HTTP) and put the tasks in right queue (use http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html pattern)
3. Create listeners for queues (1 listener with 1 thread per queue `?maxConcurrentConsumers=1`). You can create them dynamically on `setApplicationContext` event for example

Comment: Thanks Surgey, we have around 3000 accounts. I am not sure how efficient is it to configure 3000 queues and 3000 listeners. Thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this design with 2 queues, and two enterprise integration patterns: an `aggregator` and `concurrent consumers`.

The first queue is where your jobs are submitted. Let's call it `submit`. The job here is to aggregate jobs via the `accountId` and send them to another queue with in batches of `1`.

We need to run a route on *one* node only (for which we use the `master:` component)

```
from("master:myyapp:mq:queue:submit)
    .aggregate(header("accountId"), new SimpleAggregator()).completionSize(1)
    .inOut("mq:queue:process");
```

Now, you just send the job to the `process` queue, which can be processed by any server in the cluster. The key here is that we are using `inOut` pattern, which is a request-reply mode (your jms must support this).

I believe this should address the requirement where only one job should be running at any moment in time for a given account id (but you'd be wise to mock this up in some tests first).

Answer (score 0):

@vikingsteve has a good answer however I reckon it's worth looking at the [idempotent consumer](http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html) which might be a better fit for the use case.

The main reason being that the [aggregator](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html) is used to batch up many exchanges together, whereas the  will ensure it is only processing a single item for the given context (this uses the JpaRepo to store the state )

The `RouteBuilder` will look something like this:

```
// api endpoint
from("jetty:http://localhost:8080/api/submit")
    .inOnly("jms:queue:submit")
    .process(new Processor() {
        // set the response message
    });

// this implements the async processing, but will only process 
// a single accountId at a time
from("jms:queue:submit")
    .idempotentConsumer(
        header("accountId"),
        jpaMessageIdRepository(lookup(JpaTemplate.class), PROCESSOR_NAME))
    .inOut("jms:queue:process");
```

And use this camel config to have 10 jms consumers (which will enable you to run 10 operations in parallel)

```
<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Hi stringy, thanks for showing us this pattern. Question - will this allow multiple nodes to process tasks at the same time (for different account id's) ?

Comment: Yes. If you have say 10 consumers on the JMS component then they will each run in parallel. If they hit a key already registered in the idempotent store it will park the exchange and move on

Comment: Ok but should it have `master:` in the endpoint then? This will cause the logic above to only run on one node.

Comment: I just copied that from the other guys example, I'll update the answer